# Map Image Not Shown on Map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using google map api v3 . it works fine but map image not work Can u Please tell what the actual problem is . I am using google map api first time so please help Thanks In advance -- [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2crQ7/17/)

my code which i used  ---

```
<style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map { height: 80%;width:80% }
    </style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    var locations = [
  [' 1', 33.1890542, 151.274856, 'http://localhost/liveMap/app/webroot/favicon.ico'],
  [' 2', 33.0923036, 151.259052, 'http://localhost/liveMap/app/webroot/img/cake.icon.png'],
  [' 3', 34.9028249, 151.157507, 'http://localhost/liveMap/app/webroot/img/test-error-icon.png'],
  [' 4', 33.480010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 'http://localhost/liveMap/app/webroot/img/test-fail-icon.png'],
  [' 5', 33.950198, 151.259302, 'http://localhost/liveMap/app/webroot/img/test-pass-icon.png']];
  function initialize() {
    var myOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.890542,151.274856),
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),myOptions);
    setMarkers(map,locations)
  }
  function setMarkers(map,locations){
      var marker, i
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++)
 {  
 var loan = locations[i][0]
 var lat = locations[i][1]
 var long = locations[i][2]
 var add =  locations[i][3]

 latlngset = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({  
          map: map, title: loan , position: latlngset ,icon : add ,draggable:true,
        });
        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition())


        var content = "Number: " + loan +  '</h3>'     

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()

google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click', (function(marker,content,infowindow){ 
        return function() {
           infowindow.setContent(content);
           infowindow.open(map,marker);
        };
    })(marker,content,infowindow)); 

  }
  }
</script>
<body>
<div><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="return initialize()">Click Me</a></div>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try looking at the image in a browser window, does it show?

```
http://localhost/liveMap/app/webroot/img/cake.icon.png
```

Because you are using a localhost address, there is no way for us to tell.

Comment: The image in your code is coming from an http://localhost address.

That means we won't see it. If you can see it, you will be the only one because it is on your machine which we do not have access to.

Comment: problem solve , I mistakenly give latLong of ocean . so map looks blue . thanks for reply.